# Load Different headers for Specific Posts in wordpress according to their Category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am messed up with a issue. I am doing something to load different header template for all posts in category VIDEOS ( id = 109 ). I edited single.php file and on the top I replaced

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

with following code

```
<?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
if ( in_category(’109′) ) {
get_header('videos'); // use header-videos.php

} else {
get_header(); // use default header.php
}
?>
```

Before this, i already duplicated header.php file and renamed other one as header-videos.php & made changes to header-videos.php.

But, still despite all above code, default template is being loaded for all the posts including those are in categories videos .

**Any idea where am I doing wrong ?** Thanks in advance for help, please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it has to do with:

```
in_category(’109′)
```

Which should probably be:

```
in_category('109')
```

Comment: It's fine now. But as it worked, i am noticing an other type of issue. Like all the plugins those were adding content in header.php (Opengraph, SEO title,tags,)etc , those are not working in case of custom templates.. Wouldn't it load that detail in custom template of header.php ? Both have almost same code. Kindly Help, if you can please...

Comment: Unfortunately I am not that proficient in WordPress, but could probably help if you elaborate. What are the custom templates supposed to do and what is not working? Can you make it print errors?

Comment: Bro, Actually i am trying to load a different CSS & navigation menu for custom template for posts under category :Video. it will be loading different sidebar, different top header image, & different styles etc. But in case of my custom templates, special plugins that are adding SEO keywords, tittle, description meta tags & Open graph meta tags, those are not adding that info in case of custom header templates. Any idea ? Please help